Grails project - import class into build.gradle
I'm trying to define a custom Gradle task in a Grails project.
Here's the task implementation
MyCustomTask.groovy
package my.project

import my.project.stuff.DoSomething
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask

class MyCustomTask extends DefaultTask {

  @TaskAction
  void execute() {
    DoSomething.do()  // willing to re-use code already in place and working
  }

}

Then I register the task in build.gradle
build.gradle
[...]

project.tasks.register(MyCustomTask, 'exec') {
  group = 'Custom tasks'
}

But then when I reload Gradle setting for my project, I get this error:

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'myProject'.
Could not get unknown property 'MyCustomTask' for root project 'myProject' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Gradle documentation about implementing custom tasks shows as example the structure of a "Java application with the source code in the app subproject and the common build logic in buildSrc".
The project I'm working on has no subproject. Is there a way I can make this task being loaded with no error?
Thanks in advance!

Just to be sure...are you importing the MyCustomTask class?

Hi @Daniel, thanks for checking in! Actually any import my.project.MyCustomTask statement leads to the error unable to resolve class my.project.MyCustomTask
